# Probability Given Datapoint Does Not Appear in a Bootstrap Sample?

Tags: regression, bootstrap

I received this question for a Statistics / Machine Learning assignment and I'd like to you if any of you know the proper answer.

If we have n data points, what is the probability that a given data point does not appear in a bootstrap sample?

Sounds simple enough right? I'm reading Introduction to Statistical Learning to try and find the solution but I would definitely appreciate some help

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics and has been flagged for migration to Cross Validated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the probability of something not happening in n trials is something like (1 - P1)^n where P1 is the probability for one trial. What is the probability of selecting a given value? If you substitute that, does it look like an equation you know involving Euler's number `e` ??

Comment: I don't know what the probability is of finding a given datapoint from n in a bootstrap sample, we are not given any numerical values in this question. I believe it is simply 1 trial with n datapoints, but I do not know how to find the probability that one of those n datapoints will be in the bootstrap sample.

I believe the formula for this pertains directly to the way Bootstrap sampling works, but I can't seem to figure it out from other formulas for Bootstrapping.

Answer (score 0):

the probability for one trial with n data points is 1/n.
hence the equation looks like (1-1/n)**n